# Display image file in Oracle XE 11g

Tags: image, plsql, oracle11g

I am using oracle express edition 11g, I am working on creating a database that could include an image with pl-sql. I used the ***`bfile` type***, the image (jpeg) looks like it has been inserted, but then when wanting to display it using the query select, the table is displayed but the image column says:

> `"unsupported data type"`

Comment: A select statement itself is not going to "show" you an image.  I suggest you read the Oracle docs - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oralob.htm

Comment: yes I figured that out. I think I have to create a procedure for that, even for nested tables, it is the same case.
Any idea what procedure to use?

Comment: Displaying an image is a *client* thing.  The database has nothing to support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload / view images from an Oracle Database using [pl/sql Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plssql.html). Here is how:

Create your table

```
create table image (a blob);
```

## Store data

Open your table in edit mode:

```
select img.*, rowid from  image img;
```

[image: plsql edit mode]

(unlock with small icon)

Hit `+` for new record, then `..` to edit column `a` of new record; This will open a "large data editor" dialog (right):

[image: hit the + to edit column a in record][image: large data editor dialog]

Use the "Open" button, then "OK" when done, then post changes, then commit (F10): data is in the database.

## read data

After that, you can browse (hit the `...` button next to the record you want in the `a` table):

```
select img.a from image img;
```

[image: browse your images]